# Splitting Partition On External Drive

Tags: startup, partition, external-disk

I have a 1TB external drive with three partitions:

- FAT32 for extra storage (~500GB)
- Ubuntu (~499GB)
- Linux swap space (~1GB)

I want to boot to rEFind and then to Ubuntu from any Mac; preferably without destroying my Ubuntu install. I would like to split the FAT32 partition into two partitions:

- FAT32 space (500GB minus a few megabytes)
- bootable partition for rEFind (the aforementioned megabytes)

How can I do this, for free, on OS X; preferably from Terminal or Disk Utility? Would making the extra storage partition bootable work?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately OS X `Disk Utility` refuses to modify partitions on `MBR` disks. You can modify partitions form the command line using `fdisk`. If you have a `Ubuntu` machine you would be better to use this e.g. using `gparted` to resize/move/create the partitions.